# How can I compute the trajectory of something, given 3 (previous) coordinates?

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to create a simple simulation where an object follows a trajectory. I get position updates every 100ms. If I set the position of the object directly to the new (updated) position, the simulation looks really jagged. I want to make it look smooth. So I was thinking that I should probably store the 3 previous positions, and compute the current position of the object given time `t`.

My function signature would look like this:

`[xn, yn] = pos(t, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)`. Where

`[x1, y1]` is the position 300ms ago,

`[x2, y2]` is the position 200ms ago,

`[x3, y3]` is the position 100ms ago,

`[xn, yn]` is assumed position at time `t`

So at `t=0`, `[xn, yn]` is a prediction of the next position update.

Answer (score 1):

What is causing this object to move at all?  Is there a force on it?

You seem to be saying that, given three data points, you want to calculate the next point.  But given any finite data, there exist an infinite number of functions that will give that data.

It is true that, given "n" data points, there exist a unique polynomial of degree n-1 that will fit those data points.  So, given three data points there exist a unique quadratic polynomial that will fit them.  Whether that will give the trajectory depends upon the physics of the situation.  Again, what force is causing the object to move?

Here, given points $(-300, x_1, y_1)$, $(-200, x_2, y_2)$, and $(-100, x_3, y_3)$ there exist unique quadratic polynomials $x= a_xt^2+ b_xt+ c_x$ and $y= a_yt^2+ b_yt+ c_y$ such that $x_1= 90000a_x- 300b_x+ c_x$, $y_1= 90000a_y- 300b_y+ c_y$, $x_2= 40000a_x- 200b_x+ c_x$, $y_2= 40000a_y- 200b_y+ c_y$, $x_3= 10000a_x- 100b_x+ c_x$, $y_3= 10000a_y- 100b_y+ c_y$.

That is, three equations to solve for $a_x$, $b_x$, and $c_x$, and three equations to solve for $a_y$, $b_y$, and $c_y$.

Comment: The movement of the object is compute by some software. All I get is the resulting (current) position. I get this position update every 100ms, so what I want to do is move the object towards the predicted, next position. When I get the next position update, my simulation has already moved the object to it (smoothly). Then I'll start moving it to the next, predicted position, and repeat the process.

Comment: Then, given three data points and no other information, the best you can do is assume the piece-wise quadratic trajectory computed as I said.

Comment: @gromit190 You want to predict the next position of the object you are tracking (say $P_n$) using three of its previous positions (say $P_{n-1}$, $P_{n-2}$, and $P_{n-3}$). Whatever method of prediction we use, we cannot get to know the exact position of the object which is under the control of some software. Therefore, there is no way your simulation can move the object to the exact position until it is delivered to you. But, you can let your simulation to move to the predicted position first and then, wait and update this to the exact position as soon as you get it. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, this sounds like what I need.